# Angular Circular dependency detected

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular app I have three modules, core module and shared module and theme module. Core module contains all singleton services, interceptors and all. Theme module contain all third party packages . Shared module has all shared components, pipes, directions. Structure looks something like this -

```
Core ->
  --- /Services
      --- title.service.ts
      --- analytics.service.ts
      --- logger.service.ts
      --- confirm-dialog.service.ts
      --- index.ts
core.module.ts
theme.module.ts


Shared ->
  --- /components
      --- direction-map
      --- confirm-dialog
      --- index.ts
shared.module.ts
```

When I am trying to add any services from core module to any shared components getting this warnings -

[image]

**App Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { CoreModule } from '@core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from '@core/theme.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        CoreModule,
        ThemeModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Core Module**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { EnsureModuleLoadedOnceGuard } from './ensureModuleLoadedOnceGuard';
import { AjaxService } from './http';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication';
import { HTTPInterceptorProvider } from './interceptors';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards';
import {
    TitleService,
    LoggerService,
    AnalyticsService,
    ConfirmationDialogService
} from './services';

const PROVIDERS = [
    AuthGuard,
    AjaxService,
    TitleService,
    LoggerService,
    AnalyticsService,
    AuthenticationService,
    ConfirmationDialogService
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    providers: [...PROVIDERS, HTTPInterceptorProvider]
})
export class CoreModule extends EnsureModuleLoadedOnceGuard {
    /**
     * !Ensuring that CoreModule is only loaded into AppModule
     * *Looks for the module in the parent injector to see if it's already been loaded (only load once)
     *
     * @param module as parameter
     * @date: 10 Feb 2021
     * @developer: Rahul Kundu <r.kundu5@gmail.com>
     */
    constructor(
        @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule,
        _titleService: TitleService
    ) {
        super(parentModule);
        _titleService.init();
    }
}
```

**Theme Module**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
    NgModule,
    Optional,
    SkipSelf,
    ModuleWithProviders
} from '@angular/core';
import { throwIfAlreadyLoaded } from './ensureModuleLoadedOnceGuard';

// Configs imports
import { appToaster } from '@app/configs';

// Third party packages
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { OverlayscrollbarsModule } from 'overlayscrollbars-ngx';
import { NgxTippyModule, NgxTippyService } from 'ngx-tippy-wrapper';
import { LoadingBarModule, LoadingBarService } from '@ngx-loading-bar/core';

// NGX bootstrap Packages
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { RatingModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/rating';
import { SortableModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/sortable';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { ProgressbarModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/progressbar';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

const BASE_MODULES = [CommonModule];

const THEME_PROVIDERS = [CookieService, NgxTippyService, LoadingBarService];

const PLUGINS_I = [
    NgSelectModule,
    NgxTippyModule,
    LoadingBarModule,
    OverlayscrollbarsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(appToaster)
];

const PLUGINS_E = [
    ToastrModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    NgxTippyModule,
    LoadingBarModule,
    OverlayscrollbarsModule
];

const NGB_MODULES_I = [
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
];

const NGB_MODULES_E = [
    TabsModule,
    ModalModule,
    BsDatepickerModule
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [...BASE_MODULES, ...PLUGINS_I, ...NGB_MODULES_I],
    exports: [...BASE_MODULES, ...PLUGINS_E, ...NGB_MODULES_E],
    declarations: []
})
export class ThemeModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<ThemeModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: ThemeModule,
            providers: [...THEME_PROVIDERS]
        };
    }
}
```

**Shared Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// Shared Components
import {
    DirectionMapComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent
} from '@shared/components';

// Custom pipes
import {
    SummaryPipe,
    TimeAgoPipe,
    OrdinalPipe,
    FileSizePipe,
    ShortNumberPipe,
    SafeSanitizePipe
} from '@shared/pipes';

// Custom Directives
import {
    DigitOnlyDirective,
    ImgFallbackDirective,
    ClickOutsideDirective,
    InputTransformDirective,
    AutocompleteOffDirective,
    OverlayScrollbarDirective
} from '@shared/directives';

const MODULES = [CommonModule];

const CUSTOM_PIPES = [
    SummaryPipe,
    TimeAgoPipe,
    OrdinalPipe,
    FileSizePipe,
    ShortNumberPipe,
    SafeSanitizePipe
];

const DIRECTIVES = [
    DigitOnlyDirective,
    ImgFallbackDirective,
    ClickOutsideDirective,
    InputTransformDirective,
    AutocompleteOffDirective,
    OverlayScrollbarDirective
];

const SHARED_COMPONENTS = [DirectionMapComponent];

const ENTRY_COMPONENTS = [ConfirmDialogComponent];

@NgModule({
    imports: [...MODULES],
    declarations: [
        ...ENTRY_COMPONENTS,
        ...SHARED_COMPONENTS,
        ...CUSTOM_PIPES,
        ...DIRECTIVES
    ],
    exports: [...SHARED_COMPONENTS, ...MODULES, ...CUSTOM_PIPES, ...DIRECTIVES],
    entryComponents: [...ENTRY_COMPONENTS]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**direction-map.component**

```
import { LoggerService } from '@core/services';
export class ConfirmDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _logger: LoggerService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._logger.log('test');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual question? Angular has told you exactly which files are involved in each circular dependency -- all you need to do is address those issues.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas, How I can remove the warning. I have simply imported a service in shared component. I could not figured out how to resolve this.

Comment: It's complaining that you're importing from the barrel rather than the file directly, causing a loop.

Comment: oho ok i got it now, in my component i have done this - `import { LoggerService } from '@core/services/logger.service';`. Ant the warning is gone.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas I have one question from any other component except shared I can do this `import { LoggerService } from '@core/services';` But in shared why full import is there any specif reason?

Answer (score -1):

This could be happened because of a possible thing that you might be importing some service in some component and vice-versa. Component should be dependent on service but not the service should be dependent on the component. Service should only be responsible for data provider whereas component should be controller of UI. So, import the things in a sequence accordingly and hence you could avoid the circular dependency created here.